# how to make video player with javafx?

Tags: javafx

Hello everyone im trying to make a simple video player with javafx and then add some controls later with scene builder however I cant even get the simple video to play , I keep getting an error saying

```
   Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x22fda225) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x22fda225
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:110)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:107)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.start(JavaApplication3.java:45)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application javaapplication3.JavaApplication3
C:\Users\adamk\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1341: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\adamk\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I made sure that the path is correct and everything but it still wont play. can someone please help ? thanks !!!

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication3;

/**
 *
 * @author adamk
 */
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.Group;  
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

 
public class JavaApplication3 extends Application  
{  
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {  
        
    String path = "C:\\1.mp4";  
          
        //Instantiating Media class  
        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());  
          
        //Instantiating MediaPlayer class   
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);  
          
        //Instantiating MediaView class   
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);  
          
        //by setting this property to true, the Video will be played   
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);  
          
        //setting group and scene   
        Group root = new Group();  
        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);  
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,400);  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Playing video");  
        primaryStage.show();  
  }
}
```